# Sum function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum, cells

I have a problem with summing cells in vba. I need to use Cells(a,b):

```
Range("A1").function="=SUM(Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(3,2)))"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is most likely not specific enough to help you. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Do you get an error message? If so, what error message?

Answer (score 44):

Function is not a property/method from range.

If you want to sum values then use the following:

```
Range("A1").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 2)))
```

**EDIT:**

if you want the formula then use as follows:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"

'The two false after Adress is to define the address as relative (A2:B3).
'If you omit the parenthesis clause or write True instead, you can set the address
'as absolute ($A$2:$B$3).
```

In case you are allways going to use the same range address then you can use as Rory sugested:

```
Range("A1").Formula ="=Sum(A2:B3)"
```

Comment: Thanks Cabieberach ! It works, but I need sth else. Codo is right. I should have written what I expect. I would like to have formula (not just a result) in Range("A1") that sums two cells. I mean, if I change value in Cells(2,1) the value in Range("A1") should change also. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Try `Range("A1").Formula = "=Sum(A2,B3)"` You have to use the name of the cell location (A2) rather than use the Cells(2,1) vba function.

Comment: The function that works best for me is Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum()

Answer (score 10):

### **Place the function *value* into the cell**

Application.Sum often does not work well in my experience (or at least the VBA developer environment does not like it for whatever reason).

The function that works best for me is `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum()`

Example:

```
Dim Report As Worksheet 'Set up your new worksheet variable.
Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet 'Assign the active sheet to the variable.

Report.Cells(11, 1).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Report.Range("A1:A10")) 'Add the function result.
```

---

### Place the function directly into the cell

The other method which you were looking for I think is to place the function directly into the cell. This can be done by inputting the function string into the cell value. Here is an example that provides the same result as above, except the cell value is given the function and not the result of the function:

```
    Dim Report As Worksheet 'Set up your new worksheet variable.
    Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet 'Assign the active sheet to the variable.

    Report.Cells(11, 1).Value = "=Sum(A1:A10)" 'Add the function.
```

Comment: Regarding the second point: If you are wondering why your formula is in the right cell, but does not change from zero and does not throw any errors, you might have accidentally included your formula cell within the input cells (off-by-one errors are hard...)

Answer (score 3):

```
Range("A1").Function="=SUM(Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(3,2)))"
```

won't work because worksheet functions (when actually used on a worksheet) don't understand `Range` or `Cell`

Try

```
Range("A1").Formula="=SUM(" & Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(3,2)).Address(False,False) & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks man ! I deleted False, False in Address() and it works ! Now I can finish my application.

Greetings from Warsaw,
Bartek

Comment: Hi Tim, Are you using `.function` or did you meant `.WorksheetFunction` ?

Comment: Ha - should be .Formula.  That comes from just copying the OP without looking.  Will correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you , you are my hero!! I have spent all afternoon for a generic solution so I can use inside a for loop and your answer helped me to get to it 'rowRange.Cells(LastRow+1, j) = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(LastRow, j)).Address(False, False) & ")"'

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A10") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "A9"))
```

Where

`Range("A10")` is the answer cell

`Range("A1", "A9")` is the range to calculate