# How do you sum a range in a sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel

How do you sum a range in a sheet using vba.

I tried many different things but I can't figure it out. Thank you.

```
Sheet3.Sum...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba

Comment: You can use many worksheet functions within VBA. e.g. `Dim dTotal as double: dTotal = Application.Sum(Range("A1:A9"))` .

Answer (score 1):

One method would be

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim lAnswer as Long

Set rng = sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")

lAnswer = application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
```

This works because application.WorksheetFunction creates a reference to all functions available within an excel sheet.