# How to Translaste this =SUM(COUNTIFS(F4:AN4,{"0","1"})) into VBA?

Tags: vba, countif

I need help translating a common Excel function, into VBA code.

***Please see attached screenshot for the code I already have started.***

I am using the calculations seen in the screenshot to build a scorecard/grading worksheet. I will need to adjust the rows in each of these, but never the columns.

Once I figure this out, I will then loop these to repeat for each new row as they are added.

#### image of my code, so far

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum function in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba)

Comment: Post the code and not an image of it...

Comment: Google this first.

Answer (score 1):

When a literal string needs to contain double-quote characters, you need to use two double-quotes in a row for each double-quote you need in the string.

So your string

```
Range("AP4").Formula = "SUM(COUNTIFS(J3:AR3,{"0","1"}))"
```

needs to look like this:

```
Range("AP4").Formula = "SUM(COUNTIFS(J3:AR3,{"“0"”,""1""}))"
```

You can also do this without putting the formula into the content of the cell like this:

```
Range("AP4") = WorksheetFunction.SUM(WorksheetFunction.COUNTIFS(J3:AR3,{""0"",""1""}))
```