# function SUM vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the function `SUM` of different cells from different columns, I used this syntax but it doesn't work, it returns always `0`:

```
Sub test(AC As String)
    Sheets("Feuil4").Activate
    Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(Feuil2!AC10, -Feuil2!AC11)"
End Sub

Sub TEST()
    Call test("B")
End Sub
```

I also tried: `Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(Feuil2!AC & 10, -Feuil2!AC & 11)"` 
it doesn't work either.

Comment: The following subject will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

This formula

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(Feuil2!AC10, -Feuil2!AC11)"
```

subtracts sheet Feuil2 cell AC11 from Feuil2 cell AC10.

If you want to use the `AC` as column name **variable** then you must use

```
Sub WriteSumFormula(SumColumn As String)
    Sheets("Feuil4").Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(Feuil2!" & SumColumn & "10, -Feuil2!" & SumColumn & "11)"
End Sub
```

Also use descriptive variable and function names to make life easier and get better maintainable code. You cannot name 2 different subs `TEST`. Names must be unique.

Then this Test

```
Sub TestWriteSumFormula()
    Call WriteSumFormula("B")
End Sub
```

should write the formula `=SUM(Feuil2!B10, -Feuil2!B11)` into cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work too, please bear in mind I renamed one of your Subs as they can't both be named "TEST":

```
Sub TEST(AC As String)
    Sheets("Feuil4").Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(Feuil2!" & AC & "10, -Feuil2!" & AC & "11)"
End Sub

Sub TESTS() 'renamed this
    Call TEST("B")
End Sub
```