# Syntax for formula =SUM(range(cells(41,10),cells(49,10)))

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The "formula" `=SUM(range(cells(41,10), cells(49,10)))` returns "#NAME"?

I need to create the formula with quotation and `&` and place it in certain cells.
Also the values in the `Cells()` function are variables in the code.
The example is a result of one placement of the formula at a particular cell. I've tried a `:` also to separate the `cells()`, also tried not using `Range()`.

Comment: `Range` and `Cells` are not functions available to the Excel formula engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert variable into formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42503316/11683)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

```
with Worksheets("Sheet1")
   .Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & .range(.cells(41,10),.cells(49,10)).Address & ")"
End with
```