# How to create a sum function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can one use a sum function in VBA, i am trying the below piece but does not seem to work.

```
temp=Application.run("Sum",range("A1").value,range("A2").value)
Range("A1").value=temp
```

i.e
If A1=3 and A2=3
I want the end value to be 9.

Comment: sum of 3 and 3 is 9?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba)

Comment: Sorry, was a quick one, was meant to be sum of 3*3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1"),Range("A2"))
```

Be aware that if you don't state the worksheet name in front then it will implicitly use the current `Activesheet` which may not always be what you want.

You could use a `With` statement to give the parent sheet reference e.g.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1"),.Range("A2"))
End With
```

As it seems you note in your prior question: 3+3 is 6.

If you want multiplication then do:

```
temp = .Range("A1") * .Range("A2")
```

or,

```
temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Product(.Range("A1") ,.Range("A2"))
```

---

[Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run) is for running macros by their name and passing the required arguments. Unless you have a macro called `"Sum"`, I am surprised that line compiled. I also don't like macros being named after functions. It is confusing. Using the `WorksheetFunction` method as shown above is nice and clear.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies so far, what If i created my own function called CapFloor, could I call it in VBA using "Application.worksheetFunction.Product"

Comment: The main question I asked was on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951655/how-to-parse-cell-values-into-a-created-function-in-vba It will give you a more granular understanding of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying with the application.run, it says the first condition is called macro and I have no idea what they are referring to.

Comment: Having said this, the function was created by a dev team so when I open up excel I have a function called CapFloor which was created and I can call it manually by typing in a cell "=CapFloor()" , it requires 16 Inputs, if you go to this link....you will see what my main issue was, I was just not getting any traction with it so posted this one to get an idea of how to call in a function into vba etc. the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951655/how-to-parse-cell-values-into-a-created-function-in-vba

Comment: Hi, I am answering the question you have posed above rather than your other question. For the product of numbers (9 in this case) use the syntax as I have shown at the bottom. For the Application.Run scenario there must be a macro by the name referenced as the first argument present in your workbook. If your dev team developed a macro called Sum then you need to look to this. I would say 1) don't call it Sum that confuses things given it is an existing function 2) don't call it Sum when the operation is multiplication. This is misleading at best.

Comment: If they have a procedure/function called Sum that you need to include that in the above but to be honest, I would use syntax above unless there is something really important and different going on in their function/sub.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am trying to call in a .net function created by the dev team called CapFloor, I am using sum as an analogy as it works similarly in the sense of me having to type =CapFloor(x,x,x,x,x,x) in order to access it, the 'x' are the inputs, the .net function requires 16 of them. I have 16 values in row7 across 16 columns, where i point each cell into the function where I am using this formula of temp=application.run("CapFloor",temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4.....temp16) where the temp1=cell A7  temp2=cell B7 and so forth..when I run the macro using the formula above it gives

Comment: an error, but when i run it manually by pasting in the formula and its paramter values, it works...I am wondering if my application.run ("CapFloor",temp1,temp2) etc is wrong to use as when i hover over the temp1 and temp 2 etc, it is giving me the correct values, i am just thinking perhaps I am using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
Sub Sum_num()
 Dim temp As Integer
 temp = Range("A1") + Range("A2")
 MsgBox temp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you s much for the reply, A more granular question i was asking is on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951655/how-to-parse-cell-values-into-a-created-function-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

Base on my test, please try the VBA code as below:

```
Sub sum()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim tmp As Long
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
    tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(myRange)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = tmp
End Sub
```

For more information, please have a look: [WorksheetFunction.Sum Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum)

Comment: The test works, But not for the function I created, Please can you go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951655/how-to-parse-cell-values-into-a-created-function-in-vba you will see what I mean as I created a function of my own, but wont work in the same manner as you described above.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, was a quick one, was meant to be sum of 3*3

So you don't want the sum, but the product of the cells.

Use the `WorksheetFunction.Product(Range, Range2,.....)` instead of sum, the function allows for multiple ranges as parameters.

Comment: Please can you click on this link to see exactly what I am getting at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951655/how-to-parse-cell-values-into-a-created-function-in-vba