# Passing cell reference into VBA formula as argument

Tags: excel, vba, function, reference, cell

I am having an issue that I am not able to sort it out. I need to pass a cell reference as an argument in a function.

`Dim WshtRD As Worksheet`

```
Dim DI As Date
Dim RngDI As Range
Set WshtRD = ActiveSheet
AI = DateValue(Range("O3"))
With WshtRD
Set RngDI = .Range("A:A").find(What:=Format(AI, "dd/mm/yyyy"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)      
End With`


Range(RngDI.Offset(columnOffset:=3), "D2").Select
    
    
Range("Q10").Formula = "=AVERAGE()"`
```

What I would like to do is set this range

```
Range(RngDI.Offset(columnOffset:=3), "D2").Select
```

as an argument for the AVG function.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `Select`ing, use its `Address`?

Comment: After searching a lot I found out how to sort it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707888/sum-function-in-vba